how can i find Vab on a R2


How do I calculate the value of V for resistance R? I am confused about finding it using the node method. Can anyone help me find V? Thank you.

There are two resistors shown - R1 and R2. Can you edit the question to clarify which resistor you mean by How do I calculate the value of V for resistance R?

What is a vine?

sorry i mean R2

There are 9 volts across R2. If you need further help you need to take account of my comment on a previous answer.

This is a third similar question on same subject. And you don't need to calculate voltage using node method, it's the only voltage left in a closed loop. Instead of flooding one question per homework assignment, ask a generic question about what help you need to calculate these homework assignments on your own.

How do I get started?

@TenggaArlan Have you been to lectures, or have lecture notes, or a electronics book that explains these?

Because there are so many voltage sources, using the node method is not a good choice for this circuit.
First, you can remove all components that are in parallel with voltage sources because they do not affect the rest of the circuit.
Then you will have only voltage sources and R2 in your circuit.
It will be very easy to use the mesh method to solve for the voltage across R2 at that point. And from that you can determine its current.
If you insist on using the node method, you will find that because of all the voltage sources, there is only one big supernode in this circuit, and you won't actually write any node equations at all. Because of that, the "node method" becomes equivalent to the mesh method in this example, and you will just use supernode equations (which will come out to the same thing as the mesh equation from the mesh method) to find the voltage across R2.

does that mean i have to use mesh method to find V in R then?

@TenggaArlan, you don't have to. You could work it out by inspection. But between mesh and node, mesh is the better choice for this circuit. If you try to do node method, the supernode equations basically come out to what the mesh equation would have been.
